# Julia JIT compilation, @time and number of allocations

Tags: julia

I am just starting to evaluate Julia (version 0.6.0) and I tested how resize! and sizehint! could impact performance. I used @time macro.

Documentation says "# Run once to JIT-compile" but it seems that running once could not be enough if we check number of allocations.

```py
module Test

function test(x::Int64; hint::Bool=false, resize::Bool=false)
    A::Array{Int64} = []
    n::Int64 = x
    if resize
        resize!(A, n)
        for i in 1:n
            A[i]=i
        end
    else
        if hint sizehint!(A, n) end
        for i in 1:n
            push!(A, i)
        end
    end
    A[end]
end

end

import Test

#Test.test(1);  # (1)
#Test.test(1, hint=true);  # (2)
#Test.test(1, resize=true);  # (3)
@time Test.test(10_000_000)
@time Test.test(10_000_000, hint=true)
@time Test.test(10_000_000, resize=true)
```

I got different results for different "JIT-precompile" callings:

Result from code above:

```
    0.494120 seconds (11.02 k allocations: 129.706 MiB, 22.77% gc time)
    0.141155 seconds (3.43 k allocations: 76.537 MiB, 41.94% gc time)
    0.068319 seconds (9 allocations: 76.294 MiB, 76.99% gc time)
```

If (1) is uncommented:

```
    0.520939 seconds (112 allocations: 129.007 MiB, 21.79% gc time)
    0.140845 seconds (3.43 k allocations: 76.537 MiB, 42.35% gc time)
    0.068741 seconds (9 allocations: 76.294 MiB, 77.55% gc time)
```

if (1) && (2) are uncommented:

```
    0.586479 seconds (112 allocations: 129.007 MiB, 19.28% gc time)
    0.117521 seconds (9 allocations: 76.294 MiB, 50.56% gc time)
    0.068275 seconds (9 allocations: 76.294 MiB, 76.84% gc time)
```

if (1) && (2) && (3) are uncommented:

```
    0.509668 seconds (112 allocations: 129.007 MiB, 21.61% gc time)
    0.112276 seconds (9 allocations: 76.294 MiB, 50.58% gc time)
    0.065123 seconds (9 allocations: 76.294 MiB, 76.34% gc time)
```

if (3) is uncommented:

```
    0.497802 seconds (240 allocations: 129.016 MiB, 22.53% gc time)
    0.117035 seconds (11 allocations: 76.294 MiB, 52.56% gc time)
    0.067170 seconds (11 allocations: 76.294 MiB, 76.93% gc time)
```

My questions:

1. Is it bug?
2. If it is not bug then is there possibility to invoke complete compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the doc [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/#Measure-performance-with-[@time](@ref)-and-pay-attention-to-memory-allocation-1) clearly tells this is due to you were running `@time` in global scope:

```
julia> function foo()
          Test.test(1)  # warm-up
          @time Test.test(10_000_000)
          @time Test.test(10_000_000, hint=true)
          @time Test.test(10_000_000, resize=true)
       end
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()
  0.401256 seconds (26 allocations: 129.001 MiB, 47.38% gc time)
  0.185094 seconds (6 allocations: 76.294 MiB, 37.13% gc time)
  0.034649 seconds (6 allocations: 76.294 MiB, 30.99% gc time)
```

Comment: thanks for quick and helpful answer! :) Including test into function clearly help to solve problem. Could you be please more specific and copy+paste words where doc clearly described this behavior?

Comment: above the second code block: "As a teaser, an improved version of this function allocates no memory (**the allocation reported below is due to running the @time macro in global scope**) and has an order of magnitude faster execution after the first call:"