# How to measure time of julia program?

Tags: time, julia

If I want to calculate for things in Julia

```
invQa = ChebyExp(g->1/Q(g),0,1,5) 
a1Inf = ChebyExp(g->Q(g),1,10,5)
invQb = ChebyExp(g->1/Qd(g),0,1,5)
Qb1Inf = ChebyExp(g->Qd(g),1,10,5)
```

How can I count the time? How many seconds do i have to wait for the four things up be done? Do I put `tic()` at the beginning and `toc()` at the end?

I tried `@elapsed`, but no results.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The basic way is to use

```
@time begin
  #code
end
```

But note that you [never should benchmark in the global scope](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables).

A package that can help you benchmark your code is [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) which you should check out as well.

Comment: The easiest version of this is probably `using BenchmarkTools; @btime begin...`

Comment: If you do that, you have to remember to interpolate the variables though.

Comment: Especially if the variables are in global scope :joy:

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this (I guess that g is input parameter):

```
function cheby_test(g::Your_Type)
    invQa = ChebyExp(g->1/Q(g),0,1,5) 
    a1Inf = ChebyExp(g->Q(g),1,10,5)
    invQb = ChebyExp(g->1/Qd(g),0,1,5)
    Qb1Inf = ChebyExp(g->Qd(g),1,10,5)
end

function test()
    g::Your_Type = small_quick  #  
    cheby_test(g)    #= function is compiled here and 
                        you like to exclude compile time from test =#
    g = real_data()
    @time cheby_test(g)  # here you measure time for real data
end

test()
```

I propose to call @time not in global scope if you like [to get proper allocation info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262696/julia-jit-compilation-time-and-number-of-allocations) from time macro.